# Could not get unknown property 'destinationDir'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-gradle-plugin

When I upgrade the kotlin-gradle-plugin version from 1.5.0 to 1.7.20 in Android plugin project, I got this exception.

I use this code in `build.gradle`

```
compileGroovy.classpath += files(compileKotlin.destinationDir)
```

How can I solve it？

My evn is:

- gradle: 7.4
- android-gradle: 7.3.0
- kotlin-gradle-plugin: 1.7.20

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating project ':api-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not get unknown property 'destinationDir' for task ':api-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the replacement function.

```
compileKotlin.destinationDirectory.get()
```

so the question can use this code to resolve.

```
compileGroovy.classpath += files(compileKotlin.destinationDirectory.get())
```